# Appending lines with incrementing numbers to a file

Tags: linux, text-processing, numeric-data

I have a text file, and I would like to add lines to the file arranged as follows;

```
#define ICFGx     0x2y
```

where x is a decimal number that begins at 0 and ends at 255, incrementing by 1 with each line and y is a hexadecimal number that begins at 000 and ends at 3FC, incrementing by 0x004 with each line.

```
#define ICFG0     0x2000
#define ICFG1     0x2004
#define ICFG2     0x2008
#define ICFG3     0x200C
```

I would also like add them from a certain line onward, say line 500.

Is there any way to go about this task from the command line? I'm fairly new to using the linux terminal and I haven't done much bash scripting yet.

Comment: Wait, you have 4 times more x's than y's. Or do you want to increment the 0 before y when it runs out of values and start it again?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use `printf` to format the output.

```
for i in {0..255} ; do
    printf "#define  ICFG%-3d     0x2%03X\n" $i $((i*4))
done > insert.txt
```

`%d` means decimal integer, `3` is the size, the minus means aligned to the left. `X` means capital case hex, `3` is the length, `0` means 0-padded. `$(( ... ))` introduces arithmetic expansion.

Than just use `sed` to insert it into your file

```
sed -i~ 500rinsert.txt input.txt
```

Or you can use Perl:

```
perl -i~ -pe 'if ($. == 500) {
    printf "#define  ICFG%-3d     0x2%03X\n", $_, $_ * 4 for 0 .. 255 }
' -- input.txt
```

- `$.` is the input line number
- [printf](http://p3rl.org/printf) behaves similarly to the one in bash (at least for `%-3d` and `%03X`)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print}; FNR == 500 {for (i  = 0; i < 256; i++)
  printf "#define ICFG%d\t%#x\n", i, 0x2000 + i*4}' < file.h
```

To edit the file in-place, replace `awk` with `gawk` and add a `-i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`¹ option (and pass the file path as argument instead of feeding its content on `awk`'s stdin):

```
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '{print}; FNR == 500 {for (i  = 0; i < 256; i++)
  printf "#define ICFG%d\t%#x\n", i, 0x2000 + i*4}' file.h
```

With `zsh` or `ksh93` instead of `bash`, you can also generate that text with:

```
printf '#define ICFG%d %#x\n' {0..255}{,"*4+0x2000"}
```

`bash` like `ksh93` did copy the `{0..255}` from `zsh`, but does not accept arbitrary arithmetic expressions in arguments to `printf`, so you'd need to use a loop there.

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>